# Writing unit tests with Jasmine for AngularJS controller with Google maps, modals

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have been coding for so many years, but for for the first time I'm about to write test cases for an angularJS app with Jasmine... I went through many Jasmine tutorials, but most of them include simple apps like calculators or doing similar calculations. I did try it with a few tweaks and it worked fine.

But im finding it hard to implement it in some complex cases like the ones below.

for an example. Below angular code generates a map with markers on it

```
//Data
var cities = [
    {
        city : 'Toronto',
        desc : 'This is the best city in the world!',
        lat : 43.7000,
        long : -79.4000
    },
    {
        city : 'New York',
        desc : 'This city is aiiiiite!',
        lat : 40.6700,
        long : -73.9400
    },
    {
        city : 'Chicago',
        desc : 'This is the second best city in the world!',
        lat : 41.8819,
        long : -87.6278
    },
    {
        city : 'Los Angeles',
        desc : 'This city is live!',
        lat : 34.0500,
        long : -118.2500
    },
    {
        city : 'Las Vegas',
        desc : 'Sin City...\'nuff said!',
        lat : 36.0800,
        long : -115.1522
    }
];

//Angular App Module and Controller
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
.controller('MapCtrl', function ($scope) {

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.0000, -98.0000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    }

    $scope.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    $scope.markers = [];

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var createMarker = function (info){

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(info.lat, info.long),
            title: info.city
        });
        marker.content = '<div class="infoWindowContent">' + info.desc + '</div>';

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2>' + marker.content);
            infoWindow.open($scope.map, marker);
        });

        $scope.markers.push(marker);

    }  

    for (i = 0; i < cities.length; i++){
        createMarker(cities[i]);
    }

    $scope.openInfoWindow = function(e, selectedMarker){
        e.preventDefault();
        google.maps.event.trigger(selectedMarker, 'click');
    }

});
```

so when i comes to writing the test case, but it has no user inputs

```
describe('generate the map', function() {
  it('generate the map with the markers', function() {
    // how does test start?
  });
});
```

the second controller is where data is where i get values from a php file and open a modal when the user clicks.

```
 angular.module('mapsApp', [])
    .controller('userInputs', function ($scope,$modal,$location,$http) {

 $scope.fblock= [];
     $http.get('grab_from_1.php').success(function(a){
         $scope.fblock= a;
            }).error(function(data){
                $scope.fblock= a;
            });

  $scope.fblock2= [];
     $http.get('grab_from_2.php').success(function(b){
         $scope.fblock2= b;
            }).error(function(b){
                $scope.fblock2 = b;
            });



    $scope.open = function (_vals) {

        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            controller: "popin",
            templateUrl: 'get_template.php',
            resolve: {
                values: function()
                {
                    return _vals;
                },
                dates: function()
                {
                    return $scope.fblock2.filter(function (vals2) {
                        return vals2.id == _vals.id;
                    })

                }
            }
        });
    };


 }]);




    angular.module('mapsApp', []).controller('popin', function ($scope,modalInstance,$location,$http,vals1,vals2) {


      $scope.onclicking = function (cid) {
           $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
             $location.path('/information/'+cid);

        };

$scope.vals1= vals1;
$scope.vals2= vals2;


});
```

so the unit testing will be something like

```
describe('grab users from fblock 1nd fblock 2 and show a popup', function() {
  it('grab users from fblock 1', function() {

  });

 it('grab users from fblock 2', function() {

  });

it('open the popup modal', function() {

  });
```

});

Its not that i have not tried, im finding it a bit hard to apply the basics which i know to a bit complex scenario for the test controllers i have written above.

I would really appreciate if some one can help or guide me to write proper test cases using Jasmine